# Deleting node in BST without having pointer to it's parent

Tags: c, pointers, struct, binary-search-tree

I'm writing this phonebook on structures arranged into BST. It consists of two structures:

-Data structure:

```
typedef struct note
{
    char name[LENGHT];
    char surname[LENGHT];
    int tel;
}data;
```

-Node structure:

```
typedef struct junction
{
    data entry;
    struct junction* left;
    struct junction* right;
}node;
```

And i'm trying to write a function that deletes given node, but not by giving it *root* and sought value as parameters, but by giving it pointer to node to delete. The simplest case, when node is a leaf, looks like this:

```
void mDestroy(node **dNode)              
{                                       
    if((*dNode)->left==NULL&&(*dNode)->right==NULL)               
    {
        free(*dNode);
        *dNode=NULL;
        return;
    }
}
```

I've cut the rest of the code regarding other cases and search for node to replace it if it's not a leaf.
Problem is, when i run test code which creates root and 2 additional nodes, gets input from keyboard, displays them going through tree in-order(alphabetically), deletes one of non-root nodes and displays them again.
Function for traversing the tree:

```
void fDisplay(node *root)
{
    if(root->left!=NULL)
        fDisplay(root->left);
    display(root->entry);
    printf("\n\n");
    if(root->right!=NULL)
        fDisplay(root->right);
    return;
}
```

And function ACTUALLY displaying data:

```
void display(data entry)                   
{
    puts(entry.name);
    puts(entry.surname);
    printf("%d\n", entry.tel);
    return;
}
```

output actually looks like this:

```
name1
surname1
11111111111

name2
surname2
2222222222

name3
surname3
3333333333

name1
surname1
11111111111

name2
surname2
2222222222

/*some gibberish*/
surname3
3333333333
```

Assuming we delete the third entry and both are linked directly to root.
It displays the third node even though it's been set to NULL in the function.
At first I passed `*node` as argument, then I switched to `**node` and I call function like this:`mDestroy(&node1);`
Why doesn't it set the link from parent to NULL? Can it(deleting node) even be done without having parent node given as parameter or without calling it with root and having it search the tree for given value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'm assuming you are calling destroy something like this:

```
node* aNode = //create a node
node* parent = //create a node
parent.right = aNode;
mDestroy(&aNode);
```

Which is taking the address of the pointer to the `aNode` and passing that to the destroy function. That address is then dereferenced in the function to give you access to the pointer. The pointer is then freed and set to `NULL`. Now the `aNode` pointer is `NULL` but the `parent.right` pointer isn't pointing to `NULL`, it's still pointing to the old location of `aNode`.

So in order to remove the node from the tree, you must have access to the pointer in the tree pointing to that node. Then you must delete the node and set the pointer in the tree to `NULL`.

Comment: Right, that makes sense...
Then i guess there's no way to make it without function having access to that parent node...

Comment: @Pegaz, if you really think about it, you most likely wouldn't have just a pointer to a node in a tree, but rather a pointer to the root of the tree and something you want to remove from the tree. Because if you're keeping track of every pointer in the tree, separately from the tree, there's almost no point in having the tree at all.

Comment: yes, i understand that, normally it's impractical, but here I also need to write a function which will search the tree and return a pointer to a node it finds. I thought maybe i could delete it using that pointer, but now I see I won't be able to, not without for example somehow storing its parent as well.